# Autoupdate database info delivered by php script and ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

So i have the following function to get database rows from ajax.

```
function ajax_search(){ 
$("#search_results").show(); 
var search_val=$("#search_term").val(); 
$.post("find.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data){
 if (data.length>0){ 
 $("#search_results").html(data); 
} 
 }) 
 } 

 setInterval( "ajax_search();", 1000 );
```

Is there any function or way to only update the information if the database row has been edited?

Because the setInterval is not that professional as it reloads the posted page and it lags a little.

I tried with setTimeOut but it does not quite deliver what I want.

Comment: that shouldn't reload the page at all $.post() is just a shorthand version of $.ajax() which posts to the server "behind the scenes".  You might try writing out the full version of $.ajax() and see what that does for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at jQuery's dirty form plugin. Should give you what you are looking for.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dirtyform